# How to fetch values of all ec2 instances of AWS whether "AmazonCloudFormation"(using JSON) or "Non-cloud formation" (created without JSON file)

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am able to fetch details of all ec2 instances using `AmazonCloudFormation` using JAVA API which have been created using JSON file but I am unable to fetch those instance names which have not been created using JSON files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to do so using `describe-instances` from CLI. Link is as below :

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/describe-instances.html . this link [http://www.massapi.com/source/sourceforge/17/21/1721518065/vigyan-code/ogce-airavata-donation/modules/xbaya-gui/src/main/java/edu/indiana/extreme/xbaya/util/AmazonUtil.java.html#9] was also helpful